# What can I write to fix ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I can't seem to shake this exception.  I have the following code:

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :upcase_session_id     

  def self.for_session(session_id, opts)
    batch = Batch.where(session_id: session_id.upcase).first_or_initialize
    if batch.new_record?
      batch.property = opts[:property]
      batch.save!
    end
    batch
  end

  private

  def upcase_session_id
    self.session_id = session_id.upcase
  end
end
```

Calling Code:

```
def retrieve_batch
    self.batch ||= Batch.for_session(batch_session_id, property: property)
end
```

Schema Batches Table:

```
 create_table "batches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "session_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "property_id"
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_batches_on_property_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["session_id"], name: "index_batches_on_session_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

I'm not sure how I can change this code to stop getting this exception that I keep getting.

Exception:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
"index_batches_on_session_id" DETAIL: Key (session_id)=(A19A5BFD-A90C-40B4-9384-5C6C1C88213B) already exists. : 
INSERT INTO "batches" ("session_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "property_id") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id" where my schema.rb shows:
t.index ["session_id"], name: "index_batches_on_session_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Comment: Could you provide code of your `Batch` model?

Comment: The information given is not enough, but here is what I can assume:

1:) session_id is set to donwcase before save, so in your search line, where you search by `session_id.upcase` always return new record, and in save line `batch.session_id` saved as downcase, therefore the exception raised.
2:) `property` has some unique validation that need to check before `save!`.

Comment: @MikhailKatrin I updated my model code above

Comment: What exception did you get? And you don't need `save!` in `before_create` action

Comment: See title of the post

Comment: Can you post a sample call that is triggering that error? are you calling for_session, bach.create or batch.new ?

Comment: Can you show us the schema for the `Batch` table?

Comment: @nattfodd Added the schema and exception to this question

Answer (score 3):

The exception is raised when a record cannot be inserted because it would violate a uniqueness constraint. You should tell us the table constraints because the problem could be any column.

You could try this:

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord

  def self.for_session(session_id, opts)
    Batch.where(session_id: session_id.upcase).first_or_create(property: opts[:property])
  end

end
```

Comment: I still get this error with your code:

PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_batches_on_session_id"
DETAIL:  Key (session_id)=(A19A5BFD-A90C-40B4-9384-5C6C1C88213B) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "batches" ("session_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "property_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"

where my schema.rb shows:

t.index ["session_id"], name: "index_batches_on_session_id", unique: true, using: :btree

Comment: Is there any chance the index is corrupt? You could try REINDEX to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Nope.  Looks like REINDEX did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Can you show the database definition (the real types in the database, besides the migrations)?